# SQL Spatial Join - Null Values Causing Problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geospatial, spatial

I have two tables with point data. 
Table 1 - No null Points.
Table 2 - About half of the points are null.

The query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1 
INNER JOIN
  Table2 
ON
  Table1.Point.STBuffer(2.5).STIntersects(Table2.Point) = 1
WHERE
  Table1.Point IS NOT NULL
  AND Table2.Point IS NOT NULL
```

Takes over 8 hours to complete.

If I copy the data to a temporary table like this:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Point IS NOT NULL
```

The same query takes about 40 seconds.

If I add some null data back in.

```
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM Table2 WHERE Point IS NULL
```

It goes back to taking forever.

What is happening?

Comment: Have you put a geographical index on Table1.Point  and Table2.Point.  This usually is not as relevant as you might think but I thought I would ask.

Comment: Yes, these indexes are identical and present on each table and the problem persists if I include WITH(Index(SIndex_Table1_Point)): CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndex_Table1_Point
ON 
  Table1(Point)
USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (
  GRIDS = (HIGH, HIGH, HIGH, HIGH),
  CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 1
)

Comment: Your solution is usually how I end up doing all my geographical queries for speed.  In my data models I usually have a another value that lets me greatly constrain the temp table such as zip code (and all bounding zip codes) or even a county and state constraint.  I often numerical expand my point data into two fields that I can index numerically for my outer boundary select and then let the ST functions work on much smaller data sets.

Comment: How many points in Table1?  The STBuffer() isn't going to be helping query time - although I understand your need for it.  Have you tried, creating a new column with a persisted STBuffer() value?

Comment: Additionally, the nullable value may be having an adverse affect as it still resides in the Spatial Index as a record - and bloats it.  Can you take point out into a separate linked table with a record only existing for those where there is a value?

Comment: 15 million in table1, 5 million in table2.  I see your point, but if take the query and instead join table1 on itself, the query takes less than 1 minute.

Comment: @hcaelxxam "I see your point" No puns intended! :-)

Comment: @JonBellamy you are a genius.  I did not realize just how badly the spatial index handles null values.  I went ahead and did an update and set all the nulls to 0,0 and now its working.   I would have rather keep the nulls, but given my table structure, linked tables would probably be a worse solution.

Comment: @hcaelxxam you are very welcome.  You'd probably be better setting it to empty, but that's a preference.

Comment: I did not realize empty was even a thing, I haven't seen it in the documentation before.  I will absolutely try that.

Comment: @JonBellamy,  I tried using GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText('POINT EMPTY', 4326) but that had the same issue.  The only working fix is using POINT(0,0).

Comment: @hcaelxxam that is interesting.  I wouldn't have expected that.  Thanks for letting me know.  In the spirit of SO I'll put  the answer up shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spatial Indexes badly handle NULLs (and thanks to the OP's own trials EMPTY instances too).

The best solution would be to store the spatial data in a separate linked table which only contains a record for each non-null and non-empty spatial instance.

However,
One workaround which works for the OP is to set all nulls to POINT(0,0) coordinates, however for more global applications this could produce incorrect results - so the preferred method is the best if you are able to restructure the data.